# Writing text on screen affecting models

Tags: c#, graphics, xna, render

I have 3D models in my game but when I add text to the screen through spritebatch, the models disappear/become transparent.

I have looked around for a solution and found this should work if called before drawing objects

```
void prepare3d()
{
    GraphicsDevice.RenderState.DepthBufferEnable = true;
    GraphicsDevice.RenderState.AlphaBlendEnable = false;
    GraphicsDevice.RenderState.AlphaTestEnable = false;`

    GraphicsDevice.SamplerStates[0].AddressU = TextureAddressMode.Wrap;
    GraphicsDevice.SamplerStates[0].AddressV = TextureAddressMode.Wrap;
}
```

However RenderState doesnt seem to work on XNA 4.0. Anyone know of a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For XNA 4.0, you could try something like this instead:

```
void prepare3d()
{
    //set the depth buffer state
    DepthStencilState depthBufferState = new DepthStencilState();         
    depthBufferState.DepthBufferEnable = true; 
    GraphicsDevice.DepthStencilState = depthBufferState;

    //set the BlendState
    GraphicsDevice.BlendState = BlendState.Opaque;
    GraphicsDevice.DepthStencilState = DepthStencilState.Default;

    GraphicsDevice.SamplerStates[0].AddressU = TextureAddressMode.Wrap;
    GraphicsDevice.SamplerStates[0].AddressV = TextureAddressMode.Wrap;
}
```

This [Link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/06/18/spritebatch-and-renderstates-in-xna-game-studio-4-0.aspx) might be helpful.

HTH